# jQuery AJAX success not firing even though data is being captured

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that I'm submitting by AJAX and trying to replace the form once it's been submitted with a success message.

Using this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var $form    = $('#ajax_form'),
      $message = $('#thanks');

  $form.submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $form.serialize(),
      url: $form.attr('action')
    })
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.success) {
          $form.hide();
          $message.fadeIn('slow');
        }
      });

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

when I click the submit button, nothing happens, and I don't get anything written to the console. But the form is hooked up to a database and I can see in the back end that submissions are being saved.

So why is that nothing within the `done` function is returning?

Comment: Hello. have you tried `$.ajax({
url:...,
data:...,
type:...,
success:function(){

}
})`

Comment: @KiRa I hadn't before, but I have now and got the same result.

Comment: did your page gets refresh ? Also, check your network tab -> XHR see what is shown there .

Comment: @Swati There's no page refresh and the XHR tab shows a 200 status with the file = to the action of the form, type = json, transferred size = 761b. I've just tried adding `dataType: "json"` to the `$.ajax` function but got the same result.

Comment: possible to share the url where this code is implemented?

Comment: @MominIqbal Unfortunately, no I can't.